# RTOS and Micro-controllers

Tags: microcontroller, rtos, freertos

I am new to Micro-controllers and started learning AVR Micro-controllers. All I know is there are General and advanced functionality I/O pins and we need to read their respective resisters. I did a couple of projects using the same functionality.

But now I come across features that an RTOS can be embedded into a Micro-controllers for example [Micrium](https://www.micrium.com/) - now I am totally failing to understand how an OS can be embedded into a Micro-controller and how it would work with the hardware / controller?

I mean where / which address OS will be loaded and how - how will it boot on power up and start the application etc?

Comment: Actually it is not an OS, it is just source code that have to be included into a project. So using of "OS" makes no difference from the loading point of view.

Comment: how is that different from asking the same question about an x86?  or an ARM cortex-A, or a power pc, etc?

Comment: an operating system RTOS or other is just a bare metal program that runs on a system.  if you have the resources you can make small scheduler that allows other tasks to run "in parallel", an OS.  you can prioritize things and work your  way toward RTOS.  If you have the resources.

Comment: Thanks for the details I understand the concept - however please also let me know how they run TCP and have ports concept?

Comment: There are lots of documentation on site, e.g. on TCP - https://doc.micrium.com/display/TCPIPDOC/UserManual , in two words - you build one binary which includes your application and OS, application configures network using some API functions and calls some API functions to send/receive packets - all this very dependent on particular RTOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Micro-controller differs primarily from a desktop computer in size and complexity.  Its still a computer.  Its got memory to be managed, peripherals for communications, and so on.

An RTOS is just a lightweight operating system that fits on a small device.  It gives you ready-to go solutions for things like scheduling, multi-threading, inter-process synchronization, and so on.   There is plenty of functionality that has nothing to do with the peripherals.

An RTOS on a small device like an AVR will help you with high-level software challenges, but you're still going to have to understand how to configure and utilize the underlying hardware to get the best results.  Other environments (such as Arduino) will have canned code that can save you a lot of that trouble.

The RTOS environment will ship with some standard configurations - some sort of 'hello world' level application.    You'll compile that and install it on your board.  If that works, you start customizing your baseline application and go from there.   Its a lot like adding a custom library.

One thing to keep in mind is that on micro-controllers, interrupts and interrupt handlers create a lot of the same functionality that you get from RTOS threads.  There are several ways to do this.   Whether or not to use an RTOS depends on your application.  For small projects, it may not be worth it.